# Sitecore error : System.InvalidOperationException: args.Item

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

getting invalidOperationexception in Sitecore Experience editor but not happen in preview and site. See the below screenshot for more information

[image: find the exception message here]

Answer (score 1):

See at the stack trace. Exception is in line 292 of your `ControlCascadeCommandVisibility` class.

There must be something in the `Process` method which fails in Sitecore Experience Editor mode in that line.

Just debug, put a breakpoint there and see what's happening there.

Answer (score 0):

Check all renderings and remove renderings which are having empty (or) invalid Items in the DataSource.